# PHP - save an Array if a value are missing

Tags: php, arrays

I want to save two arrays in an array. 
This example works

```
    $myArray = [];
    $a = [1,2,3,4];
    $b = [1,2,3,4];
```

Output

```
Array
(
 [a] => Array
   (
   [0] => 1
   [1] => 2
   [2] => 3
   )
 [b] => Array
   (
   [1] => 11
   [2] => 22
   [3] => 33
 )
)
```

My problem is when in an array, a value is missing then it comes to an error

```
Array
(
 [a] => Array
  (
   [0] => 1
   [1] => 2
   [2] => 3
  )
 [b] => Array
  (
   [1] => 11
   [2] => 
   [3] => 33
  )
)
```

I would need output like this. If a value is missing

```
Array
(
 [a] => Array
  (
   [0] => 1
   [2] => 3
  )
   [b] => Array
  (
   [1] => 11
   [3] => 33
  )
)
```

How can i do it? 
Thank you.

Comment: Does the value of the first array reference the key of the second array? And you want to check if any values are missing from the second array, and if they are remove that element plus the related element from the first?

Comment: use if(!empty($val)){ }

Comment: Yes exactly, but second array can have a reference key to.

Comment: Unfortunately, this do not work with !empty()

Answer (score 0):

There is a function in php: `array_filter` that will remove all items from array that are equal to false (==). You can adapt this function to work recursive so it will remove all empty values from sub-arrays too.

The method should look like this:

```
function array_filter_recursive($input) 
  { 
    foreach ($input as &$value) 
    { 
      if (is_array($value)) 
      { 
        $value = array_filter_recursive($value); 
      } 
    } 

    return array_filter($input); 
  }
```

And to get your new array without empty values just call like this:

```
 $myArray = array_filter_recursive($myArray); //Or pass the array name where you have the data.
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this function a go...

```
function removeBlankElements(array & $firstArray, array & $secondArray)
{
    // Search for null, '', or false values in $secondArray
    $secondArrayRemovalIndexes = array_unique(array_merge(array_keys($secondArray, null), array_keys($secondArray, ''), array_keys($secondArray, false)));
    $firstArrayRemoveIndexes = [];
    // Build up an array of index in the $firstArray for the blank values found in the $secondArray
    foreach ($secondArrayRemovalIndexes as $secondIndex) {
        $firstIndex = array_search($secondIndex, $firstArray);
        if ($firstIndex !== false) {
            $firstArrayRemoveIndexes[] = $firstIndex;
        }
    }
    // Remove the indexes we have built up.
    $firstArray = array_diff_key($firstArray, array_flip($firstArrayRemoveIndexes));
    $secondArray = array_diff_key($secondArray, array_flip($secondArrayRemovalIndexes));
}
```

And then in practice it will look something like this:

```
// Here's the demo array you have
$x = [
    'a' => [
        0 => 1,
        1 => 2,
        2 => 3,
    ],
    'b' => [
        1 => 11,
        2 => null,
        3 => 33,
    ],
];
// Run the function passing in our 2 arrays
removeBlankElements($x['a'], $x['b']);
```

And the result..

```
var_dump($x);

array(2) {
    'a' =>
  array(2) {
        [0] =>
    int(1)
    [2] =>
    int(3)
  }
  'b' =>
  array(2) {
        [1] =>
    int(11)
    [3] =>
    int(33)
  }
}
```